# Empty files being included in a grep: More efficient to just ignore them or use arguments/piping to filter them out?

Tags: shell, awk, grep, pipe, tcsh

I have a tcsh alias set up on a server that is designed to process the apache logs for the domains hosted on it for instances of wp-login.php being accessed. After excluding the error.log files in the initial grep, it will do another grep to remove the 0 instance results, and then pipes it through awk, sort, and head for cleaner reading.

`grep -c --exclude="/var/log/httpd/domains/*.error.log" wp-login.php /var/log/httpd/domains/*.log | grep -v :0 | awk -F'\'':'\'' '\''{print $2,$1}'\'' | sort -nr | head -n 10`

Of the files being scanned by that first grep, 90% of them are empty. From an efficiency perspective, would it be better to try and work around the 1k+ empty files (and if so, how) or is the time spent processing them so small comparatively that, even if there are over a thousand empty log files being processed to just a hundred non-empty log files, the gains would be minimal?

Example output

```
# wpbf
12 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN1.TLD.log
10 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN2.TLD.log
8 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN3.TLD.log
7 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN4.TLD.log
6 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN5.TLD.log
6 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN6.TLD.log
6 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN7.TLD.log
6 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN8.TLD.log
6 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN9.TLD.log
6 /var/log/httpd/domains/DOMAIN10.TLD.log
```

Comment: `the gains would be minimal?` Yes. But try filtering with `find .. '!' -empty`. What is going on with all the `'` qoutes in `-F'\'':'\'' '\''{print $2,$1}'\''`??

Comment: Why are you doing all that escaping in your awk script (`awk -F'\'':'\'' '\''{print $2,$1}'\''`) - are you calling it from ssh or something? If so then show us that part of your script, if not you can just do `awk -F"':'" '{print $2,$1}'`. You never need grep when you're using awk btw - `grep -v :0 | awk '{foo}'` = `awk '!/:0/{foo}`.

Comment: The escaped characters are the result of some quirk, presumably in tcsh, where
`alias testtest "grep -c wp-login.php /var/log/httpd/domains/*.log | grep -v :0 | awk -F':' '{print $2,$1}' | sort -nr | head -n 10"`
works fine from the command line but fails as an alias at the awk step (need to figure out how to format the output there so it doesn't look like trash)

Comment: You know you [shouldn't write scripts in (t)csh](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not), right? That's been well-documented for decades. If you're just going to read one of the hits from that google query then I recommend https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt.

Comment: @EdMorton I've certainly noticed quirks from trying to do stuff like this in tcsh, yes. The sole reason I use it is that my boss also uses it and so years ago I started using it to prevent issues between me using bash and root using tcsh.

Comment: Time to shake the habit - it's a bad one! :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Probably should, yeah. It's not the first time I've set up something nice on the command line and then when it came time to alias it, tcsh made me change my mind. It's also not like a single shell script we write invokes tcsh either. They're all either /bin/bash or /bin/sh.  
  
I guess the end result/answer to my question is "Stop using tcsh" and that while the gains would be minimal from removing the empty files, there's still efficiency to be had in melding the second grep into part of the awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `find` with `-empty` option for files finding:

```
find /var/log/httpd/domains/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.log' '!' -name '*.error.log' '!' -empty |
xargs -d'\n' grep -Hc wp-login.php |
awk -F: '$2 != 0{print $2,$1}' | sort -nr | head -n10
```

Comment: That would certainly work, though I would want to pipe in another grep to remove the results that have 0 instances of wp-login.php popping up. No need to include those lines the rest of the way. Would my original approach of a grep -v in between the xargs and awk pipe still be the easiest way to go about that?

Comment: @Bastille Well, it will, but do the filtering in `awk`. A general rule is: the less processes you run, the faster it will be.